# Munkres lemma 13.1 and Axiom of Choice

Tags: general-topology, axiom-of-choice

[image]

In the proof it says that 'choose for each $x$ an element of $B_x$ ...' and I think that this means infinite number(If $U$ is infinite) of arbitrary choice because normally $B_x$ doesn't exist uniquely for a given $x$. But the book doesn't mention anything about this. Is it true that this proof requires axiom of choice?